How to implement multi-tenancy in FastAPI with SQLAlchemy (without using domain headers)?
I am developing a multi-tenant application using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy as the ORM. I need to implement a clean and scalable solution for multi-tenancy without relying on domain headers (e.g., tenant1.example.com).
I’m currently stuck on the architecture and looking for guidance on implementing this cleanly. Any advice, patterns, or examples would be greatly appreciated.

You can use tenant attribute for each models. Then you will be able to store your data catagorized by spessified column name.
class TenantBase(Base):
__abstract__ = True  # Ensures this base class is not mapped to a table
tenant_name = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)  # Tenant 
identifier

class User(TenantBase):
__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
username = Column(String, nullable=False)
email = Column(String, nullable=False)

also =>https://medium.com/@vivekmadurai/multi-tenancy-in-rest-api-a570d728620c
